# form action in html when jquery and ajax are used?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have below Jquery/ajax code to call a `servlet`

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./myController",
        data: dataString,
        ............

    });
```

i wrote a JQuery function which is called on submit click. i already mentioned url in AJax call as above `./myController`.

in that case what should i mention in `form action` ?

```
<form action="./myController"
```

in form action do i need to mention url as above ? because i already mentioned it in ajax call above.

Thanks!

Comment: Your form does not have to have an action defined. In the function that processes the submit, you'll want to put either `preventDefault()` or `return false;` or something like that to keep the form from actually posting and redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

action url in your form is not required here. although, you can make use of your form action in your ajax call -

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // to prevent default submit action
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: this.action,
        ......
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the url set on your ajax call is enough for your purpose, no need to change anything on form element.

As @Willem Ellis said, you'll need to prevent default behavior on using `preventDefault()` , otherwise your page will do a full post to server after performing your ajax call.

Also, from your comments, I recommend you to handle submit event like this

```
$('#theform').submit(function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault();
   ... // your ajax logic, etc
});
```

Comment: then i need not set any action on form?

Comment: Please tell me where can i do preventDefault() ?

Comment: it starts as : $(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('#theform #submit').click(function() {............

Comment: `#theform #submit`? I'm afraid that selector make no sense (although could work). That's what you have?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Afte keeping ur changes do i need to remove action tag from form?

Comment: @user1016403: it won't hurt but according what you explain, you don't need it so you could remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the action from the actual form and add a `onsubmit` tag. So the form would just fire the ajax/JQuery POST.

```
<form onsubmit="submitform();return false;">
```

Comment: @Mattthew, Thanks for your reply. Should i write a separate javascript funciton by name "submitform()" ?

Comment: Yes, you can name the function what ever you would like I was just giving an example. By using the `onsubmit` HTML tag your form will automatically call the JavaScript function and with the `return false;` at the end it will not try to actually submit the form.